# Computing the joint CDF of $(X,X^3)$ with $X$ exponential

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X\sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda)$, and let $Y=X^3$. Compute the joint CDF $F_{X,Y}$ of $(X,Y)$.

With my current understanding, I can only come up with using the one dimensional change in variable where I set $F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P((\lambda e^{-\lambda x})^3\leq y)$, then isolating for y, and then apply the transformation.

I am not sure if this is even a valid solution.

Comment: For transformation $X=Y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ Apply $g(y)=f(x)|\frac{dx}{dy}|$ Note that this formula works only when your g(x) is monotone .

Comment: $Y$ and $X$ are totally dependant. The pdf should include something like $\delta(y-x^ 3)$, the cdf something equivalent

Comment: You may use $min(y, x^ 3)$

Comment: @Damandeep That's not something that was taught in my course. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Damien Can you please elaborate on this min(y,x^3)? This is also how the textbook does it, but it doesn't provide an explanation.

Comment: @Damien Thank you. I'd appreciate that.

Comment: @Damandeep Offtopic, one is asking for the CDF, not the PDF.

Comment: @Damien There is no joint PDF.

Comment: @Did $F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P((\lambda e^{-\lambda x})^3\leq y)$ His substitution of  $Y$ is wrong .

Comment: @Damandeep More than because of details of the computation, the CDF is wrong because it applies a change of variable trick useful to compute PDFs, to a joint CDF. This is what the OP should be told, much more importantly. Thus, sorry but your first comment is actively misleading.

Comment: @Damandeep OK. Note that you can delete any of your comments.

Comment: @Damien Hmmm... Joint CDF: relevant. Joint PDF: does not exist. Thus, introducing the latter to an OP asking about the former is detrimental. " (look at my answer)" Indeed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF of $(X,Y)$ does not exist since the support of the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is a subset of the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,;\,y=x^3\}$, whose measure is zero.

To compute the CDF $F$ of $(X,Y)$, note that $$\{X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant y\}=\{X\leqslant x,X^3\leqslant y\}=\{X\leqslant x,X\leqslant y^{1/3}\}=\{X\leqslant\min\{x,y^{1/3}\}\}$$ In terms of the CDF $F_X$ of $X$, one gets

> $$F(x,y)=F_X(\min\{x,y^{1/3}\})$$

In the present case, if $x$ or $y$ is negative, then $F(x,y)=0$, and, if $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, then
$$
F(x,y)=1-e^{-\lambda\min\{x,y^{1/3}\}}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Very easy to understand.